# File_get_contents doesn't work with interpunction (ř,š)

Tags: php

i'm trying to get content of a page with *file_get_contents*, but when there is a č/ř/š in get variable (index.php?a=č), file_get_contents returns NULL.
Do you know, where's the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: use url  base64_encode or urlencode.

Comment: Try using HTML Special Characthers to encode the text like `&` to `&amp;`

Comment: Can you tell me what is your url?

Comment: Thank you (especially @Dave), I need to urlencode(get variable) and it works.